# Can multiple languages be used to develop a single .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net

Since different languages will be translated into Intermediate Language, can we use different languages to develop a single hybrid application?

Comment: probably not... but I'm not sure

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by cross-compile, except that you aren't thinking of what it actually means.

Comment: Are you asking two questions, or clarifying your initial question?

Comment: As far as I know, crosscompile means crossplatform. And .net is for Windows only. One of some popular crosscompilers is xamarin. New developments of microsoft will even go open source to support xamarin anc crosscompiling more and more. But I never heard about vb being able to crosscompile. Perhaps i just missed it.

Comment: By cross-compile, I mean, using different languages to write different parts of a project, and then to compile then together. Like calling C functions while writing R script. @icbytes

Comment: So what term should I use instead of cross-compile, do you guys get what I mean with the additional explanation? @Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET doesn't care (much) about your choice of language, a single application (multiple DDLs) can (generally) use any combination of .NET languages.  There are even ways to mix multiple .NET languages in the same DLL (assembly), but that's not supported by Visual Studio.

There are a handful of caveats when want to mix any possible combination of .NET languages as some languages have to "roll their own" in some places which can be difficult to use from another language.

Comment: The answer was accepted.. but what confuses me most is that he is talking about `VB` not `VB.Net` and `C++` not `Managed C++`. You need PInvoke to interop with them.. How does combination of .Net languages apply here, because neither `VB` not `C++` are .Net languages.